# eSQL multiple join but with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've 3 tables as under

MERCHANDISE

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| MERCH_NUM | MERCH_DIV | MERCH_SUB_DIV |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|         1 | car       | awd           |
|         1 | car       | awd           |
|         2 | bike      | 1kcc          |
|         3 | cycle     | hybrid        |
|         3 | cycle     | city          |
|         4 | moped     | fixie         |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

PRIORITY

```
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
| CUST_NUM | SALES_NUM | DOC_NUM | BALANCE | PRIORITY_1 | PRIORITY_2 | PRIORITY_CODE |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
|       90 |      1000 |      10 |      23 |          1 |          6 | NO            |
|       91 |      1001 |      20 |      32 |          3 |          7 | PRI           |
|       92 |      1002 |      30 |      11 |          2 |          8 | LATE          |
|       93 |      1003 |      40 |      22 |          5 |          9 | 1MON          |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

ORDER

```
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| CUST_NUM | SALES_NUM | DOC_NUM | COUNTRY | MERCH_NUM | MERCH_DIV |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       90 |      1000 |      10 | INDIA   |         1 | car       |
|       91 |      1001 |      20 | CHINA   |         2 | bike      |
|       92 |      1002 |      30 | USA     |         3 | cycle     |
|       93 |      1003 |      40 | UK      |         4 | moped     |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to join the left joined table from the last two tables with the first one such that the `MERCH_SUB_DIV` 'awd' appears only once for each unique combination of `merch_num` and `merch_div`

the code I came up with is as under, but I'm not sure how do I eliminate the duplicate row just for the awd

```sql
select 
  ROW#, MERCH.MERCH_NUMBER, ORDPRI.MERCH_NUMBER, ORDPRI.CUST_NUM, 
  BALANCE, SALES_NUM, ITEM_NUM, RANK, PRIORITY_1
from (
  select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY ORD.DOC_NUM, ORD.ITEM_NUM 
      ORDER BY ORD.DOC_NUM, ORD.ITEM_NUM ASC
    ) AS Row#,
    ORD.CUST_NUM, PRI.CUST_NUM, ORD.MERCH_NUM, ORD.MERCH_DIV, PRI.BALANCE,
    pri.DOC_NUM, pri.SALES_NUM, pri.PRIORITY_1, pri.PRIORITY_2 
  from ORDER as ORD 
  left join PRIORITY as PRI on ORD.DOC_NUM = PRI.DOC_NUM 
    and ORD.SALES_NUMBER = PRI.SALES_NUM
  where country_name in ('USA', ‘INDIA’)
) as ORDPRI 
left join MERCHANDISE as MERCH on ORDPRI.DIV = MERCH.DIV 
  and ORDPRI.MERCH_NUM = MERCH.MERCH_NUM
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: It seems to be your database design is flawed. I may of course be wrong here. What are the tables' keys? An order seems to be defined by sales number + document number. Is this so? But that would mean that a priority refers to a particular order. Is this intended? And why does the priority, too, have a customer number? Why can the merchandise table have duplicate rows? Your problem is probably with the database, not with the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'DISTINCT' keyword to get unique values, but if your 'Priority table' & 'Order table' contains different values for Same MERCH_NUM then the final result contains the repetation of the 'MERCH_NUM'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.MERCH_NUMBER, O.MERCH_NUMBER, O.CUST_NUM, BALANCE, SALES_NUM,ITEM_NUM,RANK,PRIORITY_1
FROM priority_table P
LEFT JOIN order_table O ON P.CUST_NUM = O.CUST_NUM AND P.SALES_NUM=O.SALES_NUM AND P.DOC_NUM = O.DOC_NUM
LEFT JOIN merchandise_table M ON M.MERCH_NUM = O.MERCH_NUM
```

Comment: I just need distinct for MERCH_SUB_DIV "awd" from the MERCHANDISE table for the rest I need all the values

Comment: @user11845701 MERCH_SUB_DIV & MERCH_NUM both are dependent... I repetation happen in oter table values with same Merch_Num then it occure in result too..

Answer (score 0):

A way around can be to add one new `Row_Number()` in the outermost query having `Partition by MERCH_SUB_DIV + all the columns in the final list` and then filter final results based on the `New Row_Number()` . Follows a pseudo code that might help:

```
select 
  -- All expected columns in final result except the newRow#
  ROW#, MERCH_NUM, CUST_NUM, 
  BALANCE, SALES_NUM, PRIORITY_1
  from (
select 
  ROW#,
  -- the new row number includes all column you want to show in final result
  row_number() over ( PARTITION BY MERCH.MERCH_SUB_DIV , 
                      MERCH.MERCH_NUM, ORDPRI.MERCH_NUM, ORDPRI.CUST_NUM, 
                      BALANCE, SALES_NUM, PRIORITY_1  
                      order by (select 1 )) as newRow# ,
  MERCH.MERCH_NUM, ORDPRI.CUST_NUM, 
  BALANCE, SALES_NUM, PRIORITY_1
 from (
      -- main query goes here
      select 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY ORD.DOC_NUM --, ORD.ITEM_NUM 
      ORDER BY ORD.DOC_NUM ASC --, ORD.ITEM_NUM 
    ) AS Row#,
    ORD.CUST_NUM, ORD.MERCH_NUM, ORD.MERCH_DIV as DIV, PRI.BALANCE,
    pri.DOC_NUM, pri.SALES_NUM, pri.PRIORITY_1, pri.PRIORITY_2 
  from @ORDER as ORD 
  left join @PRIORITY as PRI on ORD.DOC_NUM = PRI.DOC_NUM 
  and ORD.SALES_NUMBER = PRI.SALES_NUM
  where country_name in ('USA', 'INDIA')
  ) as ORDPRI 
left join @MERCHANDISE as MERCH on ORDPRI.DIV = MERCH.DIV 
  and ORDPRI.MERCH_NUM = MERCH.MERCH_NUM
) as T
-- final filter to get distinct values
where newRow# = 1
```

[Sample code here ..](https://rextester.com/QSXCO93327) Hope this helps!!